# memory leak while creating annotation points

Tags: objective-c

I found a memory leak while profiling my application

```
CustomAnnotation *annotationPoint = [[CustomAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:store.latitude longitude:store.longitude];

annotationPoint.titleLabel = store.name;
annotationPoint.subtitleLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dm", store.distance];
[annotationPoint setEvent:store];

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint]; 
[annotationPoint release];
```

This is what is specified as leaking and `annotationPoint.subtitleLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dm", store.distance];` is marked with 100%

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you calling [subtitleLabel release] in the dealloc function of Custom annotation? How are the properties defined? Assign? Retain?

Comment: `[NSString stringWithFormat]` is autoreleased by NSString. If you do not have an autoreleasepool in place, the NSString is leaking.

Comment: @guitarflow the first idea was correct. I had forgot to release in the custom annotation. Thanks. Post a solution and I will mark is at correct. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling [subtitleLabel release] in the dealloc function of CustomAnnotation?
This would solve the issue in this case, **BUT**

as I have written above : `[NSString stringWithFormat]` returns an autoreleased object.
This means that you have to use autoreleasepools to have correct memory management.